# Find $5\times5$ invertible matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ such that $A^{-1} = 2A^3 +2I$, $A \neq I$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, cayley-hamilton

I have tried to solve the above using the cayley hamilton theorem which yields nothing as I get $-1$ which is not in my field.

I feel like I need to do a sub-block decomposition.

Comment: $-1=2$ in the field.

Comment: @Berci I know, but does replacing -1 with 2  or -2 with -1 still give me a matrix which satisfies the condition above?

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be rewritten (using $2=-1$) to
\begin{align}
A^4+A+1=0
\end{align}
So we can simply choose the [Companion Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of that polynomial:
\begin{align}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0&&&-1\\
1&0&&0\\
&1&0&0\\
&&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align},

whoose characteristic polynomial (and also its minimal polynomial) is exactly $x^4+x+1$. Therefore it satisfies the formula.

But that matrix is only $4\times 4$, so you need to add an additional row/column, for example:

\begin{align}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0&&&-1&\\
1&0&&0&\\
&1&0&0&\\
&&1&-1& \\
&&&&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align},

which does not change the minimal polynomial, so the equation is still satisfied.

Comment: @ancientmathematician oh, yes of course. I corrected it in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Simon Why does adding that row and column not change the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: It does change the characteristic polynomial (which is $(x^4+x+1)(x-1)$ now). But it does not change the minimal polynomial (which is still $(x^4+x+1)$). Note that over $\mathbb{F}_3$, the polynomial $x-1$ is a divisor of the polynomial $x^4+x+1$.